# Align View below statusBar but under navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `viewController` that has a `NavigationController` as a parent. I want my `UIImageView` to be align below the `StatusBar` but under the `NavigationBar`. Is it possible without hardcoding a value programatically?

Here is my current setting:

My `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationItem.title = ""
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
```

[image]

My `ImageView` top constraint:

[image]

**And the current result:**

[image]

Comment: @matt My english might not be good, I mean the back button of the navigationBar would overlay the UIImageView

Comment: @matt right now it appear below the navbar as you can see...

Comment: @matt Sorry I forgot to share the part where I set it transparent in the code, here it is..

Comment: Could you please explain for what purpose you are trying to achieve this? Maybe there could be a better and especially cleaner solution than moving a UIImageView out of the Safe Area...